# How to rotate a bitmap inside a polygon?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, polygon, imagebrush

I defined a Polygon like this:

```
            <!-- Draws a hexagon by specifying the vertices of a polygon -->
            <Polygon x:Name="polygon"
                     Points="0,50 0,120 50,170 120,170 170,120 170,50 120,0 50,0"
                     Margin="25, 0, 25, 25"
                     Stroke="Red"
                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">

                <Polygon.RenderTransform>
                    <CompositeTransform />
                </Polygon.RenderTransform>

                <Polygon.Fill>
                    <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush"
                                ImageSource="Assets/image1.jpg"
                                Stretch="Fill">
                    </ImageBrush>
                </Polygon.Fill>
            </Polygon>
```

I also defined a storyboard like this:

```
    <Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard2">
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)"
                                       Storyboard.TargetName="polygon">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                  Value="0" />
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2"
                                  Value="-360" />
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

I start the polygon rotation like this:

```
        Storyboard2.BeginTime = new TimeSpan( 0 );
        Storyboard2.Begin();
```

The above code rotate the whole polygon as expected. However I would like to modify it, and to have the polygon stationary and just to rotate the bitmap inside the polygon.

How do I do that?
Thx

Comment: Have you tried to change the `TargetName` from "polygon" to "imageBrush"?

Comment: yes. I did but didn't do the trick. The application crashes.

Comment: Yea the crash would be expected, you need to apply a [Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush.transform) and apply the animation to it, if I have time before I head home I'll whip up an example.

Comment: I did try this:
                            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                                   <CompositeTransform/>
                            </ImageBrush.Transform>
but without success.

Comment: Rotate is all you're trying to accomplish right? Kind of wish I had a visual of the desired result since there's often more than one way to skin a cat (as the saying goes).

Comment: Brush.Transform will only support a single Transform. CompositeTransform is for folks that generally don't understand how they work which is common and no big deal, it's just an easy way to throw whatever transforms you're working with into one thing.....you'd want just RotateTransform.

Comment: Yes. Just to rotate the image inside the polygon.

Comment: Ah crap, it's UWP again, didn't you have one I was going to answer yesterday but I don't have a UWP environment until I get home and that won't be until later so I'd have to freehand it without testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rotate the image inside your polygon, you can try with [`ImageBrush.RelativeTransform` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.media.brush.relativetransform.aspx) like following:

```
<Polygon x:Name="polygon"
         Margin="25, 0, 25, 25"
         Points="0,50 0,120 50,170 120,170 170,120 170,50 120,0 50,0"
         Stroke="Red">
    <Polygon.Fill>
        <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush" ImageSource="Assets/Capture.PNG" Stretch="Fill">
            <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                <CompositeTransform CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5" />
            </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
        </ImageBrush>
    </Polygon.Fill>
</Polygon>
```

And change your `Storyboard` like following:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="Storyboard2">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames EnableDependentAnimation="True"
                                   Storyboard.TargetName="imageBrush"
                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)">
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0" />
        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:2" Value="-360" />
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Here, as the target is `ImageBrush`, so we need to change `Storyboard.TargetProperty` to `(Brush.RelativeTransform).(CompositeTransform.Rotation)`. And as the animation targets `Brush.RelativeTransform`, so it's a dependent animation. We need to set `EnableDependentAnimation` property to `true` to enable this animation. For more info about dependent animation, please see [Dependent and independent animations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/graphics/storyboarded-animations#dependent-and-independent-animations).

After this, you can call `Storyboard2.Begin();` to start the animation.

Comment: This looks more correct but I don't have a way to test at the moment. I could have sworn Brush.Transform wouldn't accept CompositeTransform though. It worked for you though Jay?

Comment: Cool so it will accept Composite? Learned something new, +1

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't test on a UWP enviro at the moment, here's how it's done in WPF, same concept...but I'm thinking the syntax may be a little different, hence why I wanted to test.

Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="SpinThisBugger" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(Brush.RelativeTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[2].(RotateTransform.Angle)" Storyboard.TargetName="polygon">
                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360"/>
            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        </Storyboard>
```

Trigger to start it:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource SpinThisBugger}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

The Poly:

```
<Polygon x:Name="polygon"
                     Points="0,50 0,120 50,170 120,170 170,120 170,50 120,0 50,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Stroke="Red"
                     RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Polygon.Fill>
                <ImageBrush x:Name="imageBrush"
                                ImageSource="Images/learn-hypnosis.jpg"
                                Stretch="Fill">
                    <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        <TransformGroup>
                            <ScaleTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <SkewTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <RotateTransform CenterY="0.5" CenterX="0.5"/>
                            <TranslateTransform/>
                        </TransformGroup>
                    </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                </ImageBrush>
            </Polygon.Fill>

        </Polygon>
```

...and the image I used, since it was nifty lol:

[image]

Comment: <ImageBrush> has only RelativeTransform
                            <ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinThisBugger"/>
                            </ImageBrush.RelativeTransform>
                        </ImageBrush>

or Transform. 
                            <ImageBrush.Transform>
                                <RotateTransform x:Name="SpinThisBugger"/>
                            </ImageBrush.Transform>

No RenderTransform

Comment: I did try your suggestion though. It didn't crash but didn't rotate either.

Comment: Yea Sorry @eitanbarazani I didn't have time to get back on last night, and it's Friday with the weekend coming. I'll del this in a bit until I have time to come back with an actually tested solution but hopefully Jay's answer is correct.

Comment: @eitanbarazani updated example with a working/tested example, but it's for WPF, so there may be some nuance differences in syntax.